# converting XSL v2 to v1

Tags: xml, xslt

I wrote an XSL that requires splitting a string down, which was nice and simple, but i then found out that the system that would then use the XSL only accepts v1 and i wrote my xsl in v2.

Having issue converting it to v1. Any help greatly appreciated.

thanks

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:soa="urn:telestream.net:soa:core"
            version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <soa:Label identifier="5f01d03f-f867-4a57-92e0-19d239a3582d" name="Duration - Timecode to Frames pt2" description="" instance="dc07adf4-79e4-4d33-b740-ece5bc0af991" signature="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
     <soa:Parameter type="timecode" identifier="82795f2a-5a2e-41ca-b1da-0c35a9c584e4" bindable="True" name="Duration Timecode" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[1]/text()[1])"/>
        <soa:Default>00:00:00:00@29.97</soa:Default>
        <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
     </soa:Parameter>
    <xsl:variable name="total-frames">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="normalize-space(/soa:Label/soa:Parameter[1]/text()[1])"
                           regex="^(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(\d+)@(\d+)$">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
             <xsl:variable name="hours" select="xs:integer(regex-group(1))"/>
             <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="xs:integer(regex-group(2))"/>
             <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="xs:integer(regex-group(3))"/>
             <xsl:variable name="frames" select="xs:integer(regex-group(4))"/>
             <xsl:variable name="fps" select="xs:integer(regex-group(5))"/>
             <xsl:value-of select="$hours * 60 * 60 * $fps + $minutes * 60 * $fps + $seconds * $frames + $frames"/>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
       </xsl:analyze-string>
   </xsl:variable> 
     <soa:Parameter type="int32" identifier="ca643595-6cbb-46b4-bf9b-da93c4348a4e" bindable="True" name="Duration Frames" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$total-frames"/>
        <soa:Default>0</soa:Default>
        <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
     </soa:Parameter>
  </soa:Label>
```

Comment: Dumping code and asking us to convert it all to XSLT v1.0 for you is unreasonable.  Try yourself and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Here's a dilemma: should I help you convert your algorithm to XSLT 1.0 - or should I tell you that your algorithm is wrong? For one thing, you are extracting the fps rate as an integer - but 29.97 is not an integer. For another, you are completely ignoring *drop-frames*.

Comment: @kjhughes i said any help appreciated, not specifically asking for someone to do it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k The default value is at 29.97 but the actual frame rate that would be populated will always be 25.

Comment: @azz2912 If it's always 25, then there is no need to extract it - just hard-code `* 25` into your formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wrote an XSL that requires splitting a string down

The splitting of a string is actually quite trivial:

Given an input of:

```
<timecode>01:02:03:04@29.97</timecode>
```

you can use:

```
<xsl:variable name="hours" select="substring-before(timecode, ':')"/>
<xsl:variable name="minutes" select="substring-before(substring-after(timecode, ':'), ':')"/>
<xsl:variable name="seconds" select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(timecode, ':'), ':'), ':')"/>
<xsl:variable name="frames" select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(timecode, ':'), ':'), ':'), '@')"/>
<xsl:variable name="fps" select="substring-after(timecode, '@')"/>
```

to extract the individual components.

Comment: thanks for that. I hadn't thought of nesting before and afters. Methods i was finding on google were rather large and convoluted.